# Change Google maps current location automatically

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

I used below code to show user current location, but when user change his location that the mark (pin) show old location instead of updated location what should I do? Using set interval or refresh every second?

```
function handle_geolocation_query(position) {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
        'bounds': true,
        'icon': 'http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocationmarker/images/gpsloc.png'
    }).click(function () {
        var a = 'Your current location!';
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
            'content': '<font color="#2a2a2a" size="4">Location </font><br/><font color="#4a4a4a">Your current location</font>'
        }, this);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to bind a handler to either the marker's `position_changed` or `dragend` event: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Comment: it has position_changed evet but what is this.it says : This event is fired when the panorama's position changes. The position changes as the user navigates through the panorama or the position is set manually.  WHAT is Panoroma position?is it user position?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking at the wrong section in the reference. Follow the link I provided and scroll down to the "Events" section in the "google.maps.Marker class" documentation.

Comment: google.maps.Marker class in here there is no position chnaged event